# jsPDF html() method split the HTML Element wrong

Tags: angular, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am using jsPDF to create an invoice report (text base!!! Images are not accepted by the client) in Angular 7 app. I have a main div with id = report which i get and pass it to the .html().In the body of the report there is a table with dynamic numer of rows. the problem is when te rows are many and the report should be splitted on two pages it is not splitting them correctly as you see in the pic:
[image]

```
pdfDoc.html(doc, {
         callback: function (pdfDoc) {
             return pdfDoc;
         },
         x: 0, y: 0
     }).
```

Please help how to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Paging by default will simply 'slice' through shapes or text chunks across page breaks. This can cut text/images in half, making it difficult to read and ruining the layout.

You will need to set the autoPaging option to 'text' like so:

```
pdfDoc.html(doc, {
     callback: function (pdfDoc) {
         return pdfDoc;
     },
     x: 0, y: 0,
     autoPaging: 'text'
 })
```

This will attempt to add page breaks gracefully between text/images/objects.

Full [documentation can be found here](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml).